# How can I select multiple columns and group them by 2 or 3 of them in SQL?

Tags: sql, group-by

I got stuck on a simple task and it sounds like this: I need to write a select query, so it returns me 5-6 columns grouped by 2-3 of them.
So, for example it would look like this:

```
Select SSN,ClientTypeId,Id,Count(SSN)
From Contact
Where ClientTypeId = 'GUID for active clients'
Group By SSN,ClientTypeId
```

All I want to do is to get a list of customers (identified by SSN) who has several active contacts.
I have found examples where multiple columns were grouped by one columns, but couldn't find something like my case. Thank you!

Comment: All non-aggregated columns should be in the `group by` - you don't actually say what your problem or actual question is?

Comment: context is required for your question. what are the columns of the table? which ones to group? what are the other columns to select?

Answer (score 0):

Your GROUP BY needs to go after your WHERE clause and all non-aggregated columns need to be in your GROUP BY e.g.

```
Select SSN,ClientTypeId,Id,Count(SSN)
from Contact 
where ClientTypeId = 'GUID for active clients'
Group By SSN,ClientTypeId,Id
```

Comment: Ooops, that's my mistake, sorry. What if I don't need to group by SSN,ClientTypeId,Id but only by SSN,ClientTypeId ?

Comment: You can't (if you also want to keep Id in your output). All columns in your SELECT clause need to use an aggregation function or be in your GROUP BY clause - so you could use MIN(Id) or something similar but that may not give you the result you want. If you update your quest with some sample data (that covers all possible scenarios) and the result you want to achieve using that data then there may be an alternative solution someone can provide